# How to debug slow Sidekiq jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq

Often times my Sidekiq jobs will be running for greater than 1 minute. I've tried to debug by sending the Sidekiq process a `TTIN` signal but I don't see anything being logged. My intuition is that it's a network request that's making it hang but I'm making use of timeouts on all network requests to address this already.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: As a suggestion, use puts to print the values of the variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking how to profile and tune slow Ruby code.

```
RubyProf.profile do
  MyJob.new.perform(...)
end
```

Output the report and review it to find where the code is slow.

https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof#usage

Answer (score 0):

You can use the benchmark module https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html

You can then save the report to a log file.